# Get cursor position before and after text input in design mode

Tags: javascript, html, textinput, designmode

I am having an iframe in design mode to implement an text editor. Now i need to know when the user inputs some text and have to know the cursor position before and after the input.

To get the current cursor position i use getSelection() of the window object which works fine. To get the position before the text input i use the before keydown event which also works fine.

The problem is that i don't find the correct event to get the position after the text was entered. I already tried after keydown and before/after keypress but within these events the old position is returned and not the new one. Before/after keyup would return the correct (new) position but this is to late and leads to a deplay in the UI.

Is there any further event i could use or any workaround to get the new cursor position before keyup event?

Comment: There is the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) event in Mozilla and WebKit (but not IE).

Comment: Solution has to work in IE9+